# windows in app delegate orientation not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I have added a notification view as toast in app delegate file i added as the class code as follows,

```
customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 54)] autorelease];
[customView setBackgroundColor: UIColorFromRGB(0xda5340)];
UILabel *lb1=[[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 17, 180, 21)] autorelease];
lb1.text=@"Pet is out of boundary";
lb1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
lb1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lb1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[customView addSubview:lb1];
[self.window addSubview:customView];
[self.window showToast:customView duration:3.0 position:@"top" ];
```

i have set my ipad ipad application as landscape , The above code working properly only with iphone when i tried in ipad its not properly oriented,the `customView` is being viewed as vertical.  i have added the following code also,

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
return YES; 
 } 

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{ 
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;  
 }
```

Should i want to added any other code ,Please help me to solve

Answer (score 0):

The simplest initial setup for the orientation is select the `summary` tab and select the orientation like as following images,

[image]

[image]